# Excel autofill date and time

Tags: excel, csv, calendar

I have a file looks like

```
5/1/2016    5/1/2016    0:00    1:00    1:00
5/1/2016    5/1/2016    1:00    2:00    1:00
5/1/2016    5/1/2016    2:00    3:00    1:00
5/1/2016    5/1/2016    3:00    4:00    1:00
5/1/2016    5/1/2016    4:00    5:00    1:00
5/1/2016    5/1/2016    5:00    6:00    1:00
5/1/2016    5/1/2016    6:00    7:00    1:00
5/1/2016    5/1/2016    7:00    8:00    1:00
```

I want to create a CSV file with such format using autofill till 1/1/2040. Please advise how to proceed.

Comment: how do you know when the date increases?  is the 5th column always 1:00?  is it a formula?   I wold normally say select your pattern and then pull down until you hit the end, but what is happening between rows for ALL columns is not clear.  Currently it looks like columns A, B, and E remain the same and Columns C and D increase by 1:00.    After 25 rows, do you have 25:00?

Comment: Thank you. It is a Google calendar. The first row means from "From 5/1/2016 0:00 to 5/1/2016 1:00 with 60 minutes of time" It will have 24 rows for every day.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to present two option to you, the first will be formulas, the second will be dates and formatting cells.

OPTION 1)

in ROW 1 enter your initial value that you want to work with then in row two enter the following formulas:

```
(Column A)
=IF(C2=0,A1+1,A1)

(Column B)
=IF(D2=0,B1+1,B1)

(Column C)
=TIME(MOD(ROW(A2)-1,24),0,0)

(Column D)
=TIME(MOD(ROW(B2),24),0,0)

(Column E)
1:00
```

Select row 2 and copy it down to about row 211057

OPTION 2)

In A1 place your starting date and time in the following format  DATE space HH:MM:SS.  So in your case,

```
5/1/2016 00:00:00
```

In B1 use

```
=A1+Time(1,0,0)
```

In C1 use

```
=A1
```

in D1 use

```
=B1
```

in E1 use

```
01:00
```

Copy B1:E1 to B2:E2

In A2 use

```
=B1
```

Select all of A2:E2 and copy down as required.

Format Column A and B to display date only,  Format column C, D, andE to display Time in the format of your choosing.  I would use 24 hour clock format HH:MM